# Rails counter_cache Balance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, counter-cache

Currently I am calculating a users balance by

```
   def balance
      transactions.where('txn_type = ?', Transaction::DEPOSIT).sum(:amount) -    
      transactions.where('txn_type = ?', Transaction::PURCHASE).sum(:amount)
   end
```

I am running a query that subtracts adds all the users deposits and subtracts all their purchases. This will not scale well when there are thousands of transactions. What would be the best approach to calculating a users balance? Is there a way to customize counter_cache to calculate this per user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can specify `:counter_sql` which will be used to set the `counter_cache`.

The [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) goes into detail about it.

Comment: I still cant find that great of documentation on it. When I specify the :counter_sql in the has_many association, it will be the default increment counter that counter_cache uses?

Comment: And does this become the default counter on the whole table?

Comment: @KyleC counter cache counts how many relations are in the relationship. It is not used as the auto-increment

Comment: So implementing a :counter_sql query will set the value of the counter_cache? THen should I setup the association just as I would with using a counter_cache then add the :counter_sql call? (sorry for all the questions)

Comment: No, the `counter_sql` should be the query that is used to get the value of the counter. (So it should be something like: `SELECT SUM(deposits) FROM transactions` ).

Comment: That being said, you are really using counter_cache wrong for this. It is meant to calculate the number of items in the relationship (`User.count`), you should just make some other field that is cached like User.balance, (maybe one that is updated using an observer on `Transaction`)

Comment: That is what I was trying to do, I wanted to add functionality like a counter_cache. I planned on added a balance column then my question was how to add/update that balance column .

Comment: You should look at putting an observer on `Transaction`, that could update the "balance" attribute on the related user. Then you can have a process on the user, that does like `recalculate` that can rebuild the balance from scratch if there are any discrepancies

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two solutions for this

1. Simple

First add `balance` column to the User model and
Add callback inside Transaction model to update the user's balance based on transaction type.

2. Complex

If you think you'll also need `deposit_amount` and `purchase amount` that too without wasting more time then `counter_culture` is what you need here.

`counter_culture` is somewhat similar to rails counter_cache but allow us to do various customizations.

This will involve following changes:

1. Add counter_culture to your Gemfile:

   gem 'counter_culture', '~> 0.1.33'

then do `bundle install`

2. Add columns `deposit_amount` and `purchase_amount` to the `users` table.

   ```
   class AddDepositAmountPurchaseAmountToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def self.change
       add_column :users, :deposit_amount, :decimal, :default => 0
       add_column :users, :purchase_amount, :decimal, :default => 0
     end
   end

   then do rake db:migrate
   ```
3. Make appropriate changes to the code

Inside Transaction model

```
counter_culture :user,
  column_name: Proc.new {|model|
    (model.txn_type == Transaction::DEPOSIT) ? 'deposit_amount' : 'purchase_amount' },
  delta_column: :amount
```

Inside User model

`def balance
    @balance ||= deposit_amount - purchase_amount
  end`

If you need more information on Counter Culture then [please read here](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture)